# Run Jasmine Tests Sequentially

Tags: testing, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Karma/Jasmine to run many spec files. My tests make use of some global functions. Some tests mock up the global functions, which other tests depend on. Since the tests are being run asynchronously, some tests fail since the expected behaviour of the global functions is changed by other tests.

**Is there a way to run the tests sequentially?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that async tests will run two tests at the exact same time.  This side effect is most likely happening because you are not reseting your global functions after the individual test ends.  If you don't restore the global function after each test and the next test that runs (which could be any individual test in your suite) could fail if it relies on the same function.

For example (using sinon)

```
describe("A suite", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      sinon.stub(someGlobal, 'someFunc')
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      someGlobal.sumFunc.restore()
    })

    it("uses global function", function() {
      ...
    });
});
```

*You can, however, set random to false in your jasmine config to run your specs in order - https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html.

Comment: You're right, I'm not resetting them. However, if a test takes too long, would karma start the execution of another test while waiting for the first one?

Comment: No, it will only run one test at a time.  It will most likely timeout and fail the individual test if it takes too long.

Comment: But is it possible to run the tests sequentially? The decrease in performance is not a big concern for me.

Comment: You can set random to false in your jasmine config to run your specs in order - https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.htm

Answer (score 9):

set "random" to false in jasmine.json

The file should be added in `spec/support/jasmine.json`

Comment: The same can be achieved inside spec code via:
```jasmine.getEnv().configure({ random: false });```

Answer (score 1):

The flag `--random=false` will run the tests sequentially. I have the script to achieve that:

```
"test": "ENV=dev && db-migrate --env dev up && jasmine-ts --random=false && db-migrate reset --env dev",
```